# ionic 2 how to reorder pages from the app.module.ts file

Tags: ionic2

when I started a blank project with ionic two it gave me a home page first.Then I created new pages since then I was under the impression that I can change my page order. For example, in my case later in development, I made a login page, and I want this page to be first before letting the user continue. I looked into it further and went into my app.module.ts and started changing the declarations order thinking that it would change the order that the pages loaded. Is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

How your pages are declared has nothing to do with how they are displayed. I recommend you read the [official docs on Navigation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/navigation/)

The first page of the app (also known as root page) is defined on app.component.ts. You can also set the rootpage by changing the variable or by calling

```
this.nav.setRoot(YourPageName);
```